# How do I transform a fraction in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about JS math.
So I'm trying to make `71.602` to look like `71(60%)` but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Why you want to make 71.602 to look like 71(60%). There is any math involved.Tell what you want then I will help you

Comment: do you want this format `71(60%)`  as a string to display it somewhere?

Comment: @JacekRojek I want to display it in a discord embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. very simple way.

```
  var str = "71.602";
  var res = str.split(".");
  var dec = res[1];
  console.log(res[0] + '(' + parseInt(dec/10) + '%)');
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also help me change this fraction `95.02586364746094` to `95.02`? Basically I want the last 12 digits gone.

Comment: Try parseFloat(95.02586364746094.toFixed(2)) should solve your problem.

Comment: That works, but what if that number `95.02586364746094` is inside a variable? Because `toFixed()` doesn't work with variables.

Comment: it works with variable. **var str = 95.02586364746094; console.log(parseFloat(str.toFixed(2)));**

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const a = 71.602
const s = a.toFixed(2).toString().split('.')
console.log(`${s[0]}(${s[1]}%)`)
```

Output

```
71(60%)
```